# How to convert Fri Mar 31 14:37:20 GMT 2023 to DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: excel, vba, date-formatting

I am would like to convert the following time string: Fri Mar 31 14:37:20 GMT 2023 to a normal European date format such as DD/MM/YYYY in VBA.

Basically, the string is formatted as text in an excel file and I am trying to turn it into a date format that I can use Excel.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Only an alternative using formula since you have tagged vba hence not posting it as an answer: `=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(" ",,CHOOSECOLS(TEXTSPLIT(A1," "),2,3,6))," ",", ",2)+0` this would return a number starting with `4` and len of 5 digits. since the dates are stored as numbers in excel, now once you get the output simply convert to date formatting you prefer

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya He needs to swap the DD and MM, so I think the CHOOSECOLS formulas has to choose columns in the order 3,2,6

Comment: @kevin the formula returns a number as an output, then he can choose the format per he likes it doesnt matter, since formatting is `Façade` also if i use 3,2,6 it won't work. In general any date formatted as text and having a format like `MMM DD, YYYY` can be converted to Excel Dates.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya The formula returns an error if CHOOSECOLS are in the wrong order. It actually depends on regional settings. If I change my regional settings to MM/DD (same as input string), then only 2,3,6 works. If I change my regional settings to DD/MM (opposite of input string), only 3,2,6 works.

Comment: Yeah, thought to update that, by that the timeline was closed, thought you are smart to figure out that. Thanks =) @kevin here is a link, it works for me, i agree with you abt the regional settings. **[Date_Conversion](https://imgur.com/gallery/IX6Og8l)**

Comment: @kevin but if you go to format cells dialog and click on dates --> select the 12th one which has a formatting `MMMM DD, YYYY` which is general i think, should not that work for all, will it be an issue with regional settings? not aware, i thought it would work. strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following function cuts the date string into pieces. If everything is good, it will convert a date out of piece 3 (day), 2 (month) and 6 (year).

Only tricky part is to convert the 3-letter month name into the month number. I have chosen a rather simple attempt be defining a (comma separated) string with all valid month names. Advantage is that this is simple and will work also when the language of your computer is not English. Disadvantage is that this will fail if the input string contains other month names (eg "Mär" for german). In that case you would need to think about a more sophisticated attempt.

I defined the return value of the function as `Variant` to be able to return `empty` when the string doesn't contain a date in the expected format.

Optional you can add the time part of the string to the returned date value.

Put the result into a cell and set the number format of that cell to the date format of your choice.

```
Function MyStringToDate(s As String, Optional withTime As Boolean = False) As Variant
    Const monthNames = "Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,Mai,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Okt,Nov,Dec"
    Dim tokens() As String
    tokens = Split(s, " ")
    If UBound(tokens) <> 5 Then Exit Function
    
    Dim month As String, day As String, time As String, year As String
    ' token(0) has the weekday - we can ignore that
    month = tokens(1)
    day = tokens(2)
    time = tokens(3)
    ' token(4) has time zone - we can ignore that
    year = tokens(5)
        
    Dim dd As Long, mm As Long, yyyy As Long
    dd = Val(day)
    mm = InStr(monthNames, month)   ' Will give 1 for Jan, 5 for Feb...
    yyyy = Val(year)
    If dd = 0 Or mm = 0 Or yyyy = 0 Then Exit Function
    mm = (mm + 3) / 4               ' Calculate real month
    
    MyStringToDate = DateSerial(yyyy, mm, dd)
    If withTime Then
        tokens = Split(time, ":")
        MyStringToDate = MyStringToDate + TimeSerial(Val(tokens(0)), Val(tokens(1)), Val(tokens(2)))
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need the mentioned as a string?

I have used the following cell format and it displays the mentioned date as the string you have mentioned.

```
DDD MMM dd hh:mm:ss "GMT" yyyy
```

(I admit, I have no idea how to add the timezone code into the cell format, that might be worthwhile investigating.)

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I think OP is asking to remove `GMT` from the text string and return only as `DD/MM/YYYY`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya: you're right. I'm not really aiming at answering the question of the author, but to give some insights which might be useful. (But seen the presence of the screenshot, it doesn't fit a comment)

Comment: No Sir, i was only curious why you gave a different solution, nothing else. but yes the one you provided is an useful way, i agree